# Parse CSV where headers contain spaces with CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a CSV file with field headers and some of them contain two or three words separated by spaces:

[image: Screenshot of the first few rows of a spreadsheet in a spreadsheet application, including headers that contain spaces, as described above.]

You can see in the above picture the field headers that contain spaces:
 "Time of Day", "Process Name", and "Image Path".

When I tried to read the CSV by calling `reader.GetRecords<DataRecord>();` (where `DataRecord` is a class I have defined), I get the error:

> Fields 'TimeOfDay' do not exist in the CSV file."*

This is because my `DataRecord` class can't contain members with spaces.

How can I use CsvHelper to parse the CSV file?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Based on CsvHelper [Documentation](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), there are several ways that we can achieve our desired results.

**1. Ignore White Space from Headers** *(which I believe should solve your problem easily)*

In CsvHelper 3 or later, use `PrepareHeaderForMatch` (documented at http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/configuration#headers) to remove whitespace from headers:

```
csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch =
    header => Regex.Replace(header, @"\s", string.Empty)
```

In CsvHelper 2, set the `IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace` flag which tells the reader to ignore white space in the headers when matching the columns to the properties by name.

```
reader.Configuration.IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace = true;
```

**2. Read Manually**

We can read each field manually like:

```
var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
do
{
    reader.Read();                   
    var record=new DataRecord();

    record.TimeOfDay=reader.GetField<string>("Time of Day");
    record.ProcessName=reader.GetField<string>("Process Name");
    record.PID=reader.GetField<string>("PID");
    record.Operation=reader.GetField<string>("Operation");
    record.Path=reader.GetField<string>("Path");
    record.Result=reader.GetField<string>("Result");
    record.Detail=reader.GetField<string>("Detail");
    record.ImagePath=reader.GetField<string>("Image Path");

} while (!reader.IsRecordEmpty());
```

**3. Class Mapping:**

We can manually map between our class's properties and the headings in the CSV file using `name class mapping` like this:

```
public sealed class DataRecordMap:CsvClassMap<DataRecord>
{
    public DataRecordMap()
    {
         Map( m => m.TimeOfDay).Name("Time Of Day");
         Map( m => m.ProcessName).Name("Process Name");
         Map( m => m.PID).Name("PID");   
         Map( m => m.Operation).Name("Operation");    
         Map( m => m.Path).Name("Path");
         Map( m => m.Result).Name("Result");
         Map( m => m.Detail).Name("Detail");
         Map( m => m.ImagePath).Name("Image Path");
     }
}
```

Then we should register it using:

```
reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DataRecordMap>();
```

Comment: While it looks good, it seems Method 1 does not work (anymore). The expected function now takes two parameters. After adding one, it however seems the returned values are not made use of, the method has no effect.

Comment: @kjyv I got it working using `csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (header, index) => Regex.Replace(header, @"\s", string.Empty);`

Comment: Just curious if anyone has written a "column name mismatch debugger" so that instead of throwing an error saying it couldnt find a match, it tried to find any columns matching any of the words in the map.  For example, I have a column named "Rating Agency" and got an error nothing existed.  While I want it to fail hard in development, I would also LOVE if in development it said, "Oh, hey John, the following columns partially match: "Rating Agencies, Ratings"

Comment: Method 1 should use class PrepareHeaderForMatchArgs so example sould look like this:
`csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => Regex.Replace(header.Header, @"\s", string.Empty)`

Answer (score 40):

The library supports [attributes](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes/) now.  You would want to use the [Name](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes/NameAttribute/) attribute.

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;

public class DataRecord
{
    [Name("Time of Day")]
    public string TimeOfDay { get; set; }

    [Name("Process Name")]
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }

    public string PID { get; set; }
    public string Operation { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }

    [Name("Image Path")]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<DataRecord> ParseDataRecords(Stream file)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(sr))
        {
            foreach (var record in csv.GetRecords<DataRecord>())
            {
                yield return record;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Couldn't get it working at first, then it turned out I had the casing of the attribute name wrong. Thanks!

Comment: This is really a time and effort saver. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

After lots of struggling with this, here's what worked for me.  I"m using version 3.

```
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.Replace(" ","")
        };

        using (var reader = new StreamReader("my_csv_file.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
```

I believe I'm creating a configuration (config) that appends or modifies InvariantCulture and uses the Replace function in C# to remove the spaces. So far it's working for me.

Comment: this does not work for me at all I still get the csv file headers with spaces sadly